# How to change crucial worldbuilding aspects midgame?

Tags: gm-techniques, world-building

In my roleplaying game, I've realized I need to change a certain crucial aspect of the world: one of the laws of magic, because it would essentially cause anyone who became powerful enough to instantly explode and die. Now my campaign is VERY hard-magic, so this is difficult to explain in-game.

Here are the details of my problem.

To understand magic in my world, there are three major concepts you need to know: Mana, Essence, and Casting. Explanations for these can be found in my WB question [here](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/217657/why-cant-you-keep-casting-wish), but I'd like to go into more detail about Essence.

Essence is what the Universe thinks of you, but the Universe has no mind of its own. It relies on the judgement of the countless sentient minds within it, giving no weight to their power, only the number of minds who believe in something. Or at least, that's what is **was**, until I realized this would makes gods almost infinitely powerful, and break an upcoming plot point where the BBEG was revealed to be someone everyone thought of as a subservient weakling. A good explanation of the old idea of Essence is Sanderson's Identity; especially in *The Emperor's Soul* (Great book. If you haven't read it, do so). The new idea of essence is heavily weighted, however, giving more weight to those who know the topic best. Of course, this means that for sentient beings, the one who knows them best is usually, if not always, themselves.

The issue, however, is with another concept: the Magiclysm Limit. A Magiclysm happens when there is too much magic stored in a single thing; when one happens, all the magic in the thing is released and something called Passive Spelling happens. Passive spelling is when magic is uncontrolled; it does something entirely random, usually bad, similar to radiation. Generally, whenever a Magiclysm happens, everything around it dies, or is mutated into a hideous monster.

The amount of magic that is able to be stored in any given object is defined by their essence; using the old definition, the BBEG would instantly magiclysm given the amount of magical power they hold.

Should I break suspension of disbelief to change this and other crucial worldbuilding aspects, or is there a better way? If so, what is it?

Comment: This is very little information — could you please elaborate on what kind of changes you want to make, what problems you predict, and what kind of assistance you seek?

Comment: Echoing the need for elaboration on this; at this point, it's not even really possible to agree that the change is necessary, let alone advise on how to change it.

Comment: I've added quite a bit of info about my problem; hopefully this is good? If not, please let me know.

Comment: @Firedestroyer As written, I think your question focuses too much on the details of your setting and not enough on the nature of the problem. Don't get me wrong, the extra information is useful - but without knowing why you're worried about sitting down with your players and saying "I'm gonna change X because of Y," it's hard to know what advice to give you.

Comment: It think it would help if you add a specific example, of how this plays out the game. It would help to be able to provide sound answers, e.g. this is the scene, what's happening, options for changing worldbuilding aspect a, b, c, etc. Hopefully then DMs will be able to provide answers with lived experience of the effect of similar conceptual and relate it to the example.

Comment: Other details that would help are WHY is this a problem, exactly, and relatedly, do your players know all of the information provided in your question? If not, how much do they know? How flexible are you on the rules of your magic system? Are your only options "let the BBEG explode" and "total retcon", or are you willing to get / looking for ways to modify your magic system in-universe? I have suggestions, but without understanding why this is a problem for you, it's just spitballing which isn't the purpose of RPG.SE.

Comment: Does your system allow to store magic in vessels that are not oneselves, e.g. making magic items or putting magic energy into a *holding pattern* that releases it as needed?

Comment: Yes, it does. Their's a lot of magic-technology that relies on essentially magic electrical systems..